# Wrap specific word in a heading with a span without losing html formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap all instances of `fubar` within any heading with a span using the following:

```
jQuery('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function(){
        var located = jQuery(this).text().replace(/fubar/g,"<span class='myspan'>fubar</span>");
        jQuery(this).html(located);
    });
```

This works fine if the text is directly inside of a H tag e.g.

```
<h1>this is fubar</h1>
```

However, if the text is wrapped inside an `a` tag, the `a` tag is stripped out, e.g.

```
<h1><a href="#">this is fubar</a></h1>
```

Becomes:

```
<h1>this is <span class="myclass">fubar</span></h1>
```

How can I retain the `a` tag and/or other wrapping elements?

---

**EDIT**

Sometimes, 'fubar' might also be in the href attribute. This should obviously not be replaced. E.g.

```
<h1><a href="#/this-is-fubar">this is fubar</a></h1>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: @Huangism sometimes 'fubar' might also be in the a href attribute.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to grab all content between tags using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `find` all children that `:contains(fubar)` and loop thru and change text.

```js
jQuery('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(':contains(fubar)').each(function(){
        var located = $(this).text().replace(/fubar/g, "<span class='myspan'>fubar</span>");
        $(this).html(located)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="#">this is fubar</a></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you!. Is there a way to prevent 'fubar' in the href attribute being replaced too? e.g. <h1><a href="this-is-fubar">this is fubar</a></h1> both instances of 'fubar' are replaced (both the text and href attribute)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `html()` to get the inner HTML of the element and replace the occurrences in it:

```js
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function() {
  var located = $(this).html().replace(/fubar/g, "<span class='myspan'>fubar</span>");
  $(this).html(located);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1><a href="#">this is fubar</a></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you!. Is there a way to prevent 'fubar' in the href attribute being replaced too? e.g. <h1><a href="this-is-fubar">this is fubar</a></h1> both instances of 'fubar' are replaced (both the text and href attribute).